# Locking background image and footer to bottom

Tags: background

I am very new to webpage design and even newer using CSS. I have agreed to help a friend out with their website. The site is www.studio9arch.net. Depending on the screen size, the background image shifts up or down, and thus the alignment of text shifts away from where it is intended to be. I would like the background to stay locked to the bottom right of the page and any overflow occurring at the top of the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Visiting your site on Android I failed to see your problem as you described it.

Comment: Currently, the background image contains the navigation and the footer info directly on the image. There are hotspots on the image for the navigation. If you view the website on an ipad for example, the horizontal bar is very low on the page. If you view it on a monitor with a high resolution, the horizontal bar of the background image is nearly in the middle of the page. What I would like is for the horizontal bar to appear at the bottom of the page on all devices and have the vertical bar grow when viewed on high resolution monitors.